# Get the sequence number of xargs command

Tags: bash, xargs

`echo a b c | xargs -n 1` will output:

```
a
b
c
```

Is there any way to get the output with sequence number as below:

```
a1
b2
c3
```

Thank you!

Hatjhie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and its special `NR` placeholder:

```
echo a b c | xargs -n 1 | awk '{print $1NR}'
```

Result:

```
a1
b2
c3
```

You can pipe those results again. Notice we set a placeholder called `%` (using `-I %`) which we can reuse. For instance:

```
echo a b c | xargs -n 1 | awk '{print $1NR".zip"}' | xargs -I % git archive -o % HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to combine with git command:
git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACMRT release..HEAD | xargs -0 git archive -o update.tar.gz HEAD

Any idea on how to do that?  So, if xargs command runs for two times, then it will have update1.tar.gz and update2.tar.gz. Thankks!

Comment: Well you can modify my example to print out the file name, then pipe it to xargs again and run any command you want

Comment: Thanks. It does not work because the source of the files to be archived is from git diff. So, it likes get the sources to be archived -> archived it but in iteration.zip. So I need two inputs here, the sources to be archived and the xargs running sequence number

Comment: Can't help you because I cannot reproduce this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a great help.